# Avoid caching for Facebook app links

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-studio, facebook-graph-api

I intergrated Facebook App Links in my Android app and it worked quite good. I followed the guide of Facebook for existing content on web (add meta-data in html web page).

However, there is an issue when I shared a link twice or more on facebook and also change the meta-data tag (like al:android:package or al:android:app_name). It seems that Facebook still work with old meta-data and cannot find my app.

Is there any way to avoid this or please give me an idea for complete Facebook App Links.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No Facebook caches it. Why do you want to change it all the time?

Comment: Because I have multiple app are using the same website. When I chang the meta-data, the suitable app should be opened

Comment: That will never work. Each URL can only point to one app. So make a unique URL for each app.